# Cookies not set on request headers. Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, session-cookies, express-session

I'm deploying an app wiht nodejs/react. I'm setting the cors as follows:

```
    const origin = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGIN;
    app.use(cors({
    origin: origin,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    credentials: true
    }));
    server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
    const host = server.address().address;
    const port = server.address().port;
    console.log(`Server listening at http://${host}:${port}`);
    })
```

```
    app.use(session({
    store: new FirestoreStore({
        dataset: firestore,
        kind: 'express-sessions',
        }),
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET, 
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false, 
        cookie: { 
            httpOnly: true, 
            domain: process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGIN, // Set your front-end domain here
            path: '/', 
            sameSite: 'Strict',
            secure: true,
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // expires in 30 days 
        }
    }));
```

I receive the cookies from the server coming from login page, but the proceeding api calls from the client to the server are not setting the cookies in the request headers.

as it is on app engine, I have my project addres but I'm using a private domain that I set as proxy. When I check the domain on my cookie, it has my default google cloud domain on it, even with my including:  domain: process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGIN, // Set your front-end domain here

if I use sameSite: 'none' instead of 'Strict', it works in google chrome but it doesn't work in other browsers, and the way it is, it doesn't work in any browser.

what am I doing wrong?